# How to take the returned value of a function and input that output in its corresponding field within a user interface with tkinter and python

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I made a function that calculates freight classification and returns a integer value.

```
def Calculate_Class(length, width, height, weight):

    cubic_inches = length*width*height #calculate cubic inches in^3
    cubic_feet = cubic_inches/1728 #convert cubic in^3 to cubic ft^3
    density = weight/cubic_feet #calculate density

    if (density > 50): #if density of cargo is over 50 pounds
        classification = 50
    elif (density > 30 and density < 50): #if density is greater than 30 and less than 35
        classification = 55
    elif (density > 30 and density < 35):
        classification = 60
    elif (density > 22.5 and density < 30):
        classification = 65
    elif (density > 15 and density < 22.5):
        classification = 70
    elif (density > 13.5 and density < 15):
        classification = 77.5
    elif (density > 12 and density < 13.5):
        classification = 85
    elif (density > 10.5 and density < 12):
        classification = 92.5
    elif (density > 9 and density < 10.5):
        classification = 100
    elif (density > 8 and density < 9):
        classification = 110
    elif (density > 7 and density < 8):
        classification = 125
    elif (density > 6 and density < 7):
        classification = 150
    elif (density > 5 and density < 6):
        classification = 175
    elif (density > 4 and density < 5):
        classification = 200
    elif (density > 3 and density < 4):
        classification = 250
    elif (density > 2 and density < 3):
        classification = 300
    elif (density > 1 and density < 2):
        classification = 400
    elif (density < 1):
        classification = 500

    return classification
```

I am trying to figure out how to input the returned value of the the Calculate_Class function and input the returned integer into the "Class" field" in the user interface. For example if the classification is 50, the integer of 50 would inserted into the Class field after filling in the length, width, height, weight fields and clicking a button to run the "Calculate Class" button.

[image: GUI]

Here is additional code relating to the the function that get the inputs for length, width, height, and user interface.

```
# this function gets the inputs from the user

def RunFunction():

    origin_zip = int(e1.get()) #gets entries stores data here
    destination_zip = int(e2.get())
    handling_unit = [e3.get()]
    pieces = [e4.get()]
    description = [e5.get()]
    length = [e6.get()]
    width = [e7.get()]
    height = [e8.get()]
    weight = [e9.get()]
    classification = []


# the follow methods generate the labels, entry fields, and format the positioning of the widgets

l6 = Label(master, text = " Length").grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = W, pady = 1)
l7 = Label(master, text = " Width").grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = W, pady = 1)
l8 = Label(master, text = " Height").grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = W, pady = 1)
l9 = Label(master, text = " Weight").grid(row = 8, column = 1, sticky = W, pady = 1)
l10 = Label(master, text = " Class").grid(row = 9, column = 1, sticky = W, pady = 1)

e6 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=10) #length(s)
e7 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=10) #width(s)
e8 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=10) #height(s)
e9 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=10) #weight(s)
e10 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=10) #class(s)

#the 40, 42, 44, 200 values are placeholders to test the function
b1 = Button(master, text = "Caculate Class", bg="yellow", 
padx=10, pady=25,command=lambda:Calculate_Class(40, 42, 44, 200)) #Calculate Class Button

b1.grid(row = 12, column = 1, sticky = E) # Calculate Class Button Positioning
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an intermediate function designed specifically for the button. The button calls the function, the function fetches the values from the form, calls `Calculate_Class`, and then  adds the return value to the GUI.

For example:

```
def set_class():

    # get the inputs
    length = int(e6.get())
    width = int(e7.get())
    height = int(e8.get())
    weight = int(e9.get())

    # calculate the classification
    classification = Calculate_Class(length, width, height, weight)

    # insert the classification into the form
    e10.delete(0, "end")
    e10.insert("end", classification)
...
b1 = Button(..., command=set_class)
```